# In Image Magick how do I remove black background areas after using -compose CopyOpacity operation for PNG file?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to make an image with rounded corners and then add a shadow effect like the output below:

[image: Desired output sample]

In the above, the input file is a jpg which worked well since there is no transparency. However, for a png file with transparency the result shows left over black arcs at the corners like the output below. Basically, it is capturing the underlying background color of the png where it is completely transparent:

[image: Bad output due to remnant black arcs at corners]

The source file I used for the above is here:

[image: Source file that needs to be enhanced with effect]

The Image Magick script that I am using so far at command line is as follows:

```
convert garfield.png \
\( +clone -alpha extract \
    \( -size 15x15 xc:black -draw 'fill white circle 15,15 15,0' -write mpr:arc +delete \) \
    \( mpr:arc \) -gravity northwest -composite \
    \( mpr:arc -flip \) -gravity southwest -composite \
    \( mpr:arc -flop \) -gravity northeast -composite \
    \( mpr:arc -rotate 180 \) -gravity southeast -composite \
\) -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite \
-compose over \( +clone -background black -shadow 80x3+5+5 \) \
+swap -background none -layers merge output.png
```

I am aware that a rounded corner effect is not possible for this png since it is transparent at the corners.  Can anyone please suggest how I may remove those black arcs at the corners in the case of png files?

Comment: I am not sure if you want to create rounded corners for every image or add shadow in case of transparent file. In the first case you could add background to your input png like this `convert -background white garfield.png -flatten + clone -alpha ...(and so on)`.

Comment: Thanks @rostok, I actually got the answer from the Image Magick forum: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=144842